# Redshift Table Ownership And Drop Query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Users & Scope -

1. write_user    - All Access to all Tables
2. read_user     - Read access to all Tables
3. backup_pruner - All GRANTS to all tables in schema backup.

My Problem Statement -

I have written an automation that has to drop tables of a schema called backup where tables are created by write_user.

Now, for dropping tables I have to user the backup_pruner user and here is the problem.
Since write_user creates table here, it is the owner of all tables in backup & Only Owners/Super-Users can drop tables.

How to Proceed from here ?

To answer the question WHY to use a separate user to DROP Tables -

To tighten the accessibility of tables as DROP if not used properly/any corner case, then can be disastrous for other tables too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a Stored Procedure created with the `SECURITY DEFINER` to drop the tables. An SP created this way runs with the permissions of the creator.

You can define a list of table names allowed to be dropped that the SP checks before taking action.

I created an example of this approach on GitHub: [`sp_controlled_access`](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/StoredProcedures/sp_controlled_access.sql)

Comment: Thanks for your help.